# How to create a source map for WebPack?

Tags: javascript, module, webpack, source-maps

My current `webpack.config` file

```
module.exports = {
    entry: "./entry.js",
    output: {
        devtoolLineToLine: true,
        sourceMapFilename: "./bundle.js.map",
        pathinfo: true,
        path: __dirname,
        filename: "bundle.js"
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            { test: /\.css$/, loader: "style!css" }
        ]
    },
};
```

I was reading here https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html and found the following:

`output.sourceMapFilename`

> [file] is replaced by the filename of the JavaScript file.
>
> [id] is replaced by the id of the chunk.
>
> [hash] is replaced by the hash of the compilation.

I've added it above as you can see, but when my webpack watch runs, I don't see a map file?

How is this done?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There are two options here:

Using the CLI [development shortcut](https://webpack.github.io/docs/cli.html#development-shortcut-d) along with your `--watch` option:

```
webpack -d --watch
```

or using the configuration [devtool](https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#devtool) option in your `webpack.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
    devtool: "source-map",
    entry: "./entry.js",
    output: {
        devtoolLineToLine: true,
        sourceMapFilename: "./bundle.js.map",
        pathinfo: true,
        path: __dirname,
        filename: "bundle.js"
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            { test: /\.css$/, loader: "style!css" }
        ]
    },
};
```

Comment: Ah thanks! This worked `webpack -d --watch` the config tool didn't do anything until I used that command.

Comment: @LeonGaban The `-d` option is just a shortcut that includes, among others, the `devtool` one. The configuration option should work with `webpack --watch`.

Comment: I think this is not either/or situation. you need to have both -- '-d' command parameter and including devtool declaration along with sourceMapFilename definition in webpack.config.js

Comment: Not sure what's wrong, but nothing from the suggestions work for me. I suspect it might be because of splitting the code into chunks (e.g. main.js, vendor.js).