# Obscure bundle.js errors in React + Webpack though Debug=true is set in the webpack.config.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

For debug purposes, I would like to get the line number which produced the error but I am getting this:

[image: error message react]

It is referencing bundle.js though I've specified debug=true in the **webpack.config.js**:

```
var path = require('path')
var webpack = require('webpack')

module.exports = {
  debug: true,
  devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map',
  entry: [
    'webpack-hot-middleware/client',
    './index'
  ],
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/static/'
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.OccurrenceOrderPlugin(),
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()
  ],
  module: {
    loaders: [{
      test: /\.js$/,
      loaders: ['babel'],
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      include: __dirname
    }]
  }
}
```

Anyway I can get the line number in the pre-compiled js?

I've tried adding pathInfo as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31878629/how-to-have-a-more-readable-bundle-js-with-webpack-sourcemap) answer recommended but to no avail.

Comment: Can you show us your `OptionGrid.js`? I have a feeling you are accessing `options` somewhere (prop, state, etc) that is undefined.

Comment: I solved the bug. The question is how do I get more specific stack traces?

Comment: I'd say that is a pretty specific stack trace. Read the stack trace from the bottom up to debug. Generally the first line is the line that causes the app to break. As I mentioned, it was caused by a reference error in `OptionsGrid.js`. You can also try out different dev tools in your webpack config such as `inline-source-map`. That's the one I use and I am very happy with it!

Comment: Also, please consider adding more information to your question or answering it yourself. That way folks after us will know what happened and it might help them solve their problem.